# Install Ubuntu on win 7laptop

Tags: boot

My niece gave me a Windows 7 laptop which has Short DST Failed errors on startup. Can I use a flash drive to install Ubuntu on this laptop so that I can use it?

Comment: Can't you just replace the hard drive with a new one (maybe even a SSD for speed)?

Comment: I would if I had the money but right now that isn't an option lol.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  The instructions are listed here:

- https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu
- https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

Instructions for Windows:

1. Download the [Rufus USB installer](https://rufus.akeo.ie/)
2. Open Rufus and select your USB stick in the 'Device' dropdown
3. Click the CD Rom icon next to the 'FreeDOS' dropdown, then find your downloaded Ubuntu ISO and click 'Open' and then 'Start'
4. Click 'Yes' when it asks to download Syslinux software
5. Click 'OK' to write in ISO Image mode
6. Confirm that your USB stick is selected and then 'OK' to continue

When it is finished, just restart your computer and start using Ubuntu, or you can install Ubuntu

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you. Been using Ubuntu for a couple years and love it but desktop comp died and I replaced it with this laptop.

Comment: I see, so you have no functioning PC at all?

Comment: No I can get on my friends and set up the USB drive

Comment: Excellent.  Well, these are the details you want then.  There are other methods as well.  You can look at using `dd` to transfer the disk image to USB via command line, or if you prefer, you could use https://unetbootin.github.io to do it with a GUI :)

Comment: Thank you all so much. This is what I love about Ubuntu. It would have probably taken a week to get an answer anywhere else,